# Preventing pointer invalidation when using pop_back

Tags: c++, pointers

If there's a pointer pointing to the last element of a vector, and I want to remove the element but keep the data via a pointer, how can I do it?

```
vector<int> a;
a.push_back(1);
int * b = a[0];
a.pop_back();     //b is invalidated
```

Am I forced to use a different container or is there another way?

Comment: [The docs say](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/pop_back) `void pop_back(); Removes the last element of the container. No iterators or references except for back() and end() are invalidated.`

Comment: [The end iterator and any iterator, pointer and reference referring to the removed element are invalidated.](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/pop_back/)  Are you sure?

Comment: Nevermind, just noticed you want to keep a pointer to a now-removed object, thats obviously not possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the question it seems you specifically want to keep a pointer an element which is removed from the container. All containers invalidate pointers and references to erased objects. If you need to erase an objects from a container but keep the pointed to object alive, the only standard library container viable is a `std::list<T>`: you can `splice()` the object into a different list:

```
std::list<int> a;
std::list<int> removed;

a.push_back(1);
int* b = &a.front();
a.splice(a.begin(), removed);
```

After this operation the object pointed to by `b` isn't in `a` but it is in `removed` instead.

Comment: Is it possible to transfer the value from a list to a single variable/pointer via splice()? Or does it have to be a list as well?

Comment: `splice()` can only transfer the object to another list of the same type.

Answer (score 2):

The vector keeps an internal copy of the data, so you cannot rely in general on pointers to the internal data (push_back or pop_back may invalidate them). You can make a copy, `int b = a[0];` in your code, or store pointers in the vector instead of values. Note that in the latter case you need to be careful with memory management, use `vector<unique_ptr<T>>` for instance.